# Додекаэдр в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Озадачился построением додекаэдра в matplotlib. Получилось построить только правильный пятиугольник. Какие дальнейшие манипуляции необходимо произвести с кодом, чтобы из таких пятиугольников образовался додекаэдр? Необходимый результат - заполненная матрица dodecahedron, описывающая вектора (рёбра) фигуры

```
 x=0 #центр полигона (x)
 y=0 #центр полигона (y)
 z=0
 n=5  #число сторон полигона
 r=10  #радиус окружности в которую вписываем полигон
 #получаем координаты вершин
 dodecahedron=[]#матрица векторов (рёбер) додекаэдра
 a=[]
 k=0
 for i in range(1,n+2):
     a.append((x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * i / n), y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * i / n), z))
     k+=1
     if k==2:
         dodecahedron.append(a)
         a=[(x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * i / n), y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * i / n),z)]
         k=1
```

Comment: какой-то странный подход к решению задачи: налепить плоских многоугольников и ждать, что они образуют какую-то трехмерную фигуру. Берите формулу поиска вершин додекаэдра, исходные параметры, и рассчитывайте.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться формулой координат вершин додекаэдра:

> Если центр додекаэдра совпадает с началом координат, его вершины можно определить по координатам: (±1, ±1, ±1); (0, ±1/φ, ±φ); (±1/φ, ±φ, 0); (±φ, 0, ±1/φ), где φ = (1+√5)/2 — золотое сечение. ([Правильний додекаедр](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80), укр. язык)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У ДДКЭ 20 вершин и 30 рёбер.

1. (±1, ±1, ±1) - это 8 комбинаций, соотвественно 8 вершин. Это вершины вписанного куба, красные/серые рёбра на картинке, с координатами;
2. (0, ±1/φ, ±φ) - это ещё четыре вершины. Берём z в плюсе (±1, ±1, 1) и (0, ±1/φ, φ), соединяем (0, 1/φ, φ) и (0, -1/φ, φ) (1-ое ребро), а потом (0, 1/φ, φ) с (±1, 1, 1) (2-ое и 3-ье), а (0, -1/φ, φ) с (±1, -1, 1) (4-ое и 5-ое). Для z в минусе делаем то же самое: получаем ещё пять рёбер, соединяя (0, 1/φ, -φ) с (0, -1/φ, -φ), (0, 1/φ, -φ) с (±1, 1, -1), (0, -1/φ, -φ) с (±1, -1, -1). Всего десять рёбер.
3. (±1/φ, ±φ, 0) - ещё четыре вершины и десять рёбер. Сначала берём y в плюсе, потом в минусе.
4. (±φ, 0, ±1/φ) - ещё четыре вершины и десять рёбер.  Сначала берём x в плюсе, потом в минусе.

Получили все тридцать рёбер. То есть на каждом шаге 2 - 4 вы вычисляете по 10 ребёр и добавляете их в матрицу.

Если нужно изменить размер, то умножаете каждую координату на коэффициент.

Если нужно переместить центр в другую точку, то к каждой координате добавляете соотвествующую координату центра.

Comment: А зачем цитата на украинском?

Comment: @Глеб Потому что это цитата. Надеюсь, понятно. В статье про додекаэдр на русском почему-то этих формул нет. Пытался перевести уже после публикации ответа, но почему-то  на сайте сбоит редактирование.

Comment: А, понял. Тоже сейчас пытался вопрос отредактировать, а не сохраняется почему-то.

Comment: @Глеб ну вот, перевёл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблема в том, что эти формулы я находил, но совершенно не понимаю как, сохранив свой вывод - матрицу векторов(что необходимо для дальнейшей программы), изменить свой код. С соединением тоже есть проблемы, поскольку в компьютерной графике разобраться тяжеловато.

Comment: Добавил материала.

Comment: Как продвигается?